# Operator overload generic CollectionType fails

Tags: swift

I'm trying to overload the `-=` operator to get the same (but reversed) behaviour as the `+=` overload on CollectionType and SequenceType. However, I'm running into trouble with the following code:

```
func -=<Element, C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Element>(inout lhs: [Element], rhs: C)
{
    lhs = lhs.filter { !rhs.contains($0) }
}

func -=<Element, S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(inout lhs: [Element], rhs: S)
{
    lhs = lhs.filter { !rhs.contains($0) }
}
```

It results in the unfortunately, not very specific error of `Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'`, which essentially just translates to "wrong arguments, somewhere". But I can't figure out why the closure passed to the filter isn't valid, given the generic constraints in the function signature?

(This is, of course, Swift 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contains()` requires that the elements are `Equatable`, so you have
to add that as a constraint:

```
func -=<Element, C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Element, Element : Equatable>(inout lhs: [Element], rhs: C)
{
    lhs = lhs.filter { !rhs.contains($0) }
}

func -=<Element, S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element, Element : Equatable>(inout lhs: [Element], rhs: S)
{
    lhs = lhs.filter { !rhs.contains($0) }
}
```